# Android: стоит ли стремиться минимизировать количество символов в именах и идентификаторах?

Tags: java, android, xml

Стоит ли в целях увеличения быстродействия и сокращения занимаемого объёма памяти стремиться минимизироватья количество символов в идентификаторах и именах ресурсов?

Вот пример имён строк от самого длинного, но понятного, до короткого, но требующего задуматься, что это значит:

- `string name="menu_item_set_everyday_tasks"`
- `string name="menui_set_everyday_tasks"`
- `string name="menui_seteverydaytasks"`
- `string name="menui_setevrdtasks"`
- `string name="setevrdtasks"`
- `string name="setevrdtsks"`

Разумеется, что данное обсуждение значимо, когда мы имеет в одном приложении порядка нескольких сотен ID, строковых ресурсов и т. д.

Comment: быстродействие от этого не увеличится, память - незначительно. Есть смысл использовать специальные минимизаторы (самый простой - proguard). Но в коде должны быть понятные имена, иначе через полгода можно будет долго смотреть на названия a/b/c...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, не нужно.
XML-файлы ресурсов не попадают в скомпилировнный код в чистом виде. Вместо этого cреда разработки автоматически преобразовывает строковые имена в числовые идентификаторы и помещает их в виде статических числовых констант в класс `R.java`.  А числовые переменные, как известно, занимают фиксированное количество байт.

Более подробно, например, тут: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/resources.php#string

Comment: А есть какой-то код стайл для XML как Google выпустил для Java под Android?

Comment: @Kostya здесь что-то есть: https://github.com/google/styleguide

Answer (score 1):

> Разумеется, что данное обсуждение значимо, когда мы имеет в одном приложении порядка нескольких сотен ID, строковых ресурсов и т. д.

Не стоит даже в этом случае.